# É uma boa prática não fechar o arquivo .php com ?> após uma chamada XHR feita de um arquivo .html?

Tags: php, ajax, xhtml

Devo fechar a tag do PHP `<?php` com o `?>`? Um amigo com mais experiência me recomendou a não fechar dizendo que era uma "Boa prática de programação", nunca entendi o porquê, mas sigo a recomendação desde então.

**Isto é realmente uma boa prática? Por que?**

Comment: Por isso "boas práticas" são sempre horrorosas, elas viram mantras repetidos sem contexto. **Nunca use uma boa prática**. Faça o certo em cada contexto. Se não souber "o certo" estará errando de alguma forma, mesmo seguindo uma "boa prática". Programar por coincidência não deixa de ser um erro. O conselho que posso lhe dar é sempre pedir uma explicação fundamentada do que a pessoa está dizendo quando sugere que você faça algo em programação (isto vale para blogs e respostas no SOpt :) ). Saber "por que?" é a parte mais importante da programação e provavelmente de qualquer área de conhecimento.

Comment: [*It's a newbie coding style recommendation. That's why it's typically mentioned in introductory books.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag/4465825#4465825) Eu acostumei a remover desde que passei horas e mais horas caçando o bug do espaço extra no fim do arquivo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[PHP DOC](http://php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation)

> A tag de fechamento de um bloco PHP ao final de um arquivo é opcional, e em alguns casos omiti-la é útil ao usar include ou require, assim espaço em branco indesejado não irá aparecer ao final dos arquivos, e você ainda será capaz de adicionar cabeçalhos a resposta após. Também é útil se você usar output buffering, e você não quer ter adicionado um espaço em branco ao final das partes geradas por arquivos incluídos.

Quando você omite a tag de fechamento `?>` evita espaços em branco ou quebras de linha que podem ocorrer de forma acidental ao final do arquivo. Por esse motivo muitos programadores escolhem em não fechar e você encontra muitos frameworks que adotam este procedimento.

1. Se você omite o fechamento e escapar um caractere, você receberá um erro de sintaxe: *Parse error: syntax error*.
2. Se você fechar a tag `?>` e acidentalmente escapar um caractere, você pode receber um: *Warning: Cannot modify header information*, isso porque haverá uma saída antes dos cabeçalhos.

Comment: Isso que chamo de uma resposta libertadora capaz de esclarecer bastante coisa.