# PHP - abertura/fecho

Tags: php

Olá. Alguém me pode explicar porque razão o site do facebook (e muitos outros sites) não têm tags de abertura/fecho de php? Eu sei que eles usam php.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É uma boa prática não fechar o arquivo .php com ?> após uma chamada XHR feita de um arquivo .html?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31912/%c3%89-uma-boa-pr%c3%a1tica-n%c3%a3o-fechar-o-arquivo-php-com-ap%c3%b3s-uma-chamada-xhr-feita-de)

Comment: Não é que não tem, é que você não vê isso. O PHP funciona do lado do servidor, ele processa as requisições e devolve apenas um HTML pro browser.

Comment: @Everson Duplicada????

Comment: @LINQ verificou a resposta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31913/57801 se encaixa na pergunta. E outra coisa, Facebook desenvolveu sua própria linguagem que é o Hack , podendo ser verificado em http://hacklang.org/

Comment: @Everson O que a resposta tem a ver com o código PHP não aparecer no client-side?

Comment: @LINQ em qual momento está definido que o problema está no "client-side", o problema está descrito em 2 linhas. E ser "Possível duplicata de" significa que pode ou não ser uma duplicata. Que pelas regras da comunidade irá ser verificado por um supervisor.

Comment: @Everson O único motivo pras tags não aparecem no browser, é porque elas não são renderizadas no client-side, por motivos óbvios. Perceba que a pergunta é dele é "por que não têm as tags de **abertura e** fechamento". Ou seja, ele está tentando ver o código pelo browser e, obviamente, não acha as tags. Sobre o "possível" duplicata, eu sei como o sistema funciona e, pra fins de conhecimento, nenhum supervisor precisa confirmar nada, se 5 pessoas votarem para fechar a pergunta será fechada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, sua resposta está mais correta. O problema está na compreensão do problema. Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: PHP roda no back-end processa e entrega via "resposta/download" somente o html, não é possivel ler o php via navegador, ele só esta no servidor e lhe entrega o que desejar, leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635

Comment: @LINQ não apenas as tags, mas sim todo o conteúdo não é exibido. Mas como falei, 2 linhas não descrevem o problema em si.

Answer (score 1):

As tags de abertura e fechamento do PHP são processadas no servidor. Quando você visualiza o fonte de uma página feita em PHP através do navegador, essas tags nunca serão exibidas.

Comment: Já percebi. Obrigado. É que as tags não apareciam em nenhum site. Parece que tenho ainda muito a aprender, eheh.